# Get value form ajax request and give global variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Sorry folk, I know that  my question asked many guys in different form, but I'm disappointed to  find a decision my  problem.

```
function testAjax(){       
     var result = "";
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         dataType: 'jsonp',
         url: "https://api.novaposhta.ua/v2.0/json/",
         data: {
             "modelName": "Address",
             "calledMethod": "getCities",
             "methodProperties": {}, 
             "apiKey": "6f94a6391cb5134ee68ddb7924de2a3d"
         },
         success: function(msg) { result = msg }});
     return result;
}
var kor = testAjax();
console.log(kor);
```

I need to take out `data` from the ajax request and assign this `data` to a global variable. But function `testAjax` returns nothing. I think `testAjax` returns nothing because it's an async request to server and completes later  than `return result`.
My question  - how do I take out a value from `$.ajax()` and assign this value to a global variable? I tried googling and try decide this problem, but ...

Comment: `kor` is in global scope, so you can assign `msg` to it from the success function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your hunch is correct - the function is returning `result` as an empty string because the success handler is called later when the server response is returned. If you wish to do something specific when the response comes in, do so in the success response handler like so:

```
...
success: function(msg) {
    // now you have the response so do something with it
    console.log(msg);
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

most of the time the logic go inside the success function, whatever you will do with the response do it inside the success function.I think you may bay more time for the code structure and the flow of data inside your app.
good luck